# Using IValueConverter to convert binded text to an image

Tags: wpf

I have a grid where I want to take the text from that cell, convert it to an image and send it back to the grid.

Here is my template code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="categoryCellTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0"
               Margin="1,1,4,1"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource catConverter}}"
               />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

and here is my xaml code:

```
<Grid>
    <xcdg:DataGridControl Height="311" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                          Name="dataGridControl1" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                          Width="503"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Clients}}">
        <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
            <xcdg:Column FieldName="Name" />
            <xcdg:Column FieldName="Age" />
            <xcdg:Column FieldName="Category" />
            <xcdg:Column FieldName="Color"
                         CellContentTemplate="{StaticResource categoryCellTemplate}" />
            <xcdg:Column FieldName="DOB" />
        </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl>
</Grid>
```

where i am having trouble in the template code is to specify what the parameter is.... since he data is bound, I dont know how to send it to the converter class.. please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what kind of parameter you want to pass. You can use the `ConverterParamter` like this

```
Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource catConverter}, ConverterParameter='some parameter'}"
```

however the `ConverterParameter` is not a dependency property so you cannot use binding. If you want to supply dynamic context you would need to use multi binding and a multi value converter like this:

```
<Image.Source>
    <MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource catMultiConverter}>
      <Binding .../>
      <Binding .../>
    </MultiBinding>
</Image.Source>
```

Comment: well, I basically want to pass the Category value into that as the parameter. Category is an integer value {1, 2, 3, 4} and the Convert function will return a bitmap image, now the converter class is good. its just the parameter i need to pass.  not quite sure how to pass a parameter. The Color field is also an integer value {1, 2, 3, 4} possibilities. and the converter class will convert that int into an image... i guess i should have given more information in the question

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In your example it shows that that you have a cel ltemplate for the `Color` field. Does that mean that you converter depends on the color value **and** the category value?

Comment: yes. the Color value is the same as the Category value... so in my Person class.. i have a property that goes like this...                         public int Color{ get { return this.Category;}}... i did further investigation... the parameter "value" in the Convert() is always passing null value. this has to be strange because I have written the function and the way to display a picture the same way as other programmers have done it. this has become frustrating

Comment: Well, if you just want to pass in a single value into your converter then the approach you have should already work. If the value passed into the converter is null then it indicates that the DataContext for your template is not set properly. You don't seem to use a standard Grid so maybe the problem is there?

Comment: I was able to get this working. in my Convert(), I was returning a Bitmap image object which I had trouble setting up. All I ended up doing was returning the location of my picture as a string and it worked... so much code for nothing!