# WPF: display a collection of datagrids in a custom format (with image)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding, user-controls, observablecollection

I have 2 classes, one inside the other, and a prop with an ObservableCollection of the class with the sub-class collection. But I'm having a serious trouble in displaying the whole thing.

First my data, this is what I've got: (it may clarify my issue)

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Front { get; set; }
    public Props.StateSemaphore Semaphore{ get; set; } // this is an enum w/ints
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
    public string Architect { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public MyItem(){}
    public MyItem(string id, string front, 
            Props.StateSemaphore semaphore, string toolTip, 
            string architect, string status)
    {
        Id = id;
        Front = frente;
        Semaphore = semaphore;
        ToolTip = toolTip;
        Architect = architect;
        Status = status;
    }
}

public class MyTab
{
    public List<MyItem> MyItems { get; set; }
    public string Environment { get; set; }
    public MyTab() { }
    public MyTab(string environment)
    {
        Environment = environment;
        MyItems = new List<MyItem>();
    }
}
```

And a prop on the PageExample.xaml.cs

```
  private ObservableCollection<MyTab> myPanel;
  public ObservableCollection<MyTab> MyPanel
  {
      get { return myPanel; }
      set { myPanel = value; }
  }
```

The idea is to display for each *Environment* a Grid of MyItems with an image(Red, Yellow or Green) on the semaphore enum

***@Edit: This is almost working! Only the images won't display.***

This is My XAML but im newbie on wpf so It's obvious I’m missing something.

```
<Page x:Class="MyBoard.PageMain"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyBoard"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="PageMain">
       <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <DataGrid Name="EnvironmentDataGrid" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Front}" Header="Front"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Semaphore">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Semaphore}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ToolTip}" Header="ToolTip"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Architect}" Header="Architect"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Environment}" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="3"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander>
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" Margin="8,0,4,0"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="Element(s)"/>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

These are my questions:

1. How is the correct way to write the XAML? @Edit: **DONE!**
2. How and where to bind
   the semaphore image to the datagrid?

***@Edit: Semaphore is now a RelativeUri, because I didnt understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5544077/684646).
I mean, I get the idea but not this thing:***

```
<MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource catMultiConverter}>
      <Binding .../>
      <Binding .../>
    </MultiBinding>
```

With the RelativeUri and all It still does not display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples) to find out how to set `DataGrid.Columns` and how to `Bind` them.
2. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543878/using-ivalueconverter-to-convert-binded-text-to-an-image) how to convert semaphore enums into Images thru `Converter` and `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`.
3. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283720/manually-group-datagrid-items) how to use grouping in `DataGrid` to group on the `Environment` property so that same `Environment` items are shown arranged under one group.

Comment: I'll be checking this answer as the correct one as soon as everything here works for me, thanks!

Comment: The first link is for windows apps, mine is web, does this do any difference?

Comment: You can search how silverlight datagrid is assigned with columns and how they are bound.

Comment: Almost working! I still have the image issue, I added Update items to the question, any help or orientation you can give me would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Dont try relative URI first, try absolute URi and check if the images are displaying. E.g. if your relative URI is "..\Images\MyImage.gif" then use to "C:\blablah\myproject\Images\MyImage.gif" instead and verify if the images load atleast with the absolute Uri.